# Pass an index on event trigger in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a small custom plugin that I am building inside which I am triggering an event when I click on a certain item. When the item in clicked with left mouse, the following is triggered:

```
Holder.KeyboardPlugin.prototype.triggerExpansion = function() {
if(this.expandedItem){
    var changedGroupSource = null;
    Holder.events.trigger(this, 'groupselect', function(changedGroup){
    changedGroupSource = changedGroup;
    });
  }
};
```

`Holder.events.trigger` has the following code :

```
function (object, event, properties) {
        var index = this.indexOf(object);
        var listener = this.listeners[index];
        if (listener) {
            var callbacks = listener.events[event];
            if (callbacks) {
                for (var i = 0, iMax = callbacks.length; i < iMax; i++) {
                    callbacks[i](properties);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem here is that the in my triggerExpansion() method above, functionally everything is fine right now. I am passing a class function to `triggerProperties` and through that callback function, I am modifying the plugin internal `changedSource` variable.
However, along with this, I also want to pass the index (a certain number) of the selected group to the listener in my html (that uses plugin). Since, I have already passed the callback function, I am not able to resolve on how I should be passing a certain index along with the callback function as well here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like:

```
Holder.events.trigger(this, 'groupselect', {
    index: theIndex,
    callback: function(changedGroup){...}
});
```

so in the event listener you will have event.index and event.callback.

Is that what you need?